# Saving registers values before system call

Tags: unix, assembly, nasm, cpu-registers

In my x86 ASM textbook there is an [example](http://www.stolyarov.info/files/stud_io_inc_linux) of a macro which writes a string in the standard output stream:

```
%macro  PRINT 1
    pusha
    pushf
    jmp %%astr
%%str   db  %1, 0
%%strln equ $-%%str
%%astr: _syscall_write 1, %%str, %%strln
    popf
    popa
%endmacro
```

What I can not understand is why do we push and pop all general purpose registers values to / from the stack? `_syscall_write` does not modify any registers but `EAX` which will hold the result of the system call. So why don't we just push and pop just `EAX`? Won't it be more efficient?

Comment: Just for sanity's sake, did you try just pushing EAX and then examining the other registers to ensure they're the same?

Comment: @alex I just tried pushing and poping `EAX` and all the registers remained the same as I expected. `ESP` changed back and forth of course.

Comment: Maybe it's a *best practice* thing, that is, push and pop all because the function potentially may modify registers. I guess it comes down to how efficient you want the code to be (for some uses, like this, it seems the performance gain isn't worth the potential future maintenance issue).

Comment: @alex thank you for an answer. I still don't get your point in the 1st comment. Shall some registers change after `push`ing and `pop`ing `EAX`?

Comment: The system call could change them and not clean up after, I believe. Been a while since I've played with x86 assembly though.